# OpenCV can`t find image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I am trying the basic tutorial found here http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/40-1-load-and-display-an-image which handles loading and displaying an Image. I an doing it in Visual Studio 2012.

I have placed the image file "lena.png" in the Debug folder beside the exe file. When I try to execute the exe file from the terminal it simply replies "Cannot load image!". I have also tried this in the Release folder with the same result.

This is the code I have for the program:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc > 1){
        cout << argv[1] << endl;
    }

    Mat img = imread("lena.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why this hapens, the picture is in the same directory as the .exe and I am following the example code to the letter. Please help me understand why it can`t find the file!

EDIT:
HAHAHAHAHA I fixed it. In a rage fit I changed all the additional dependencies from *.lib to *d.lib since I am running the debugging version and it worked. If I read the tutorial on how to use opencv it says that there is a difference but since it compiled I thought that it would work. I am going to try the release version now and see if it works (with changing the dependencies back of course).

EDIT 2:
Yea it worked. So the answer to my own question is that you need to link the correct .lib files from the include folder as dependencies for the debug and release build. The ones ending with "d" for debug and the others for release. Maybe not so surprising now that I found the problem but there it is.

Comment: Most probably your image is of some other format other than png

Comment: try to place image in solution folder.(where *.cpp files)

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but I get the same result. I am really stumped by this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the file formats for `imread`. Try with a `.jpg` or any of the valid image formats.To quote from [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imread),

`The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image can not be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).`

Comment: I tried with both .jpg and .bmp but still the same result. I also tried placing the pictures in the solution directory with the .cpp file but to no avail.

Comment: Could it perhaps have something to do with permissions as it said in the page you linked? I usually work with linux so I do not know how to check that I have read and write permissions in windows.

Comment: Ok it seems like the picture allows SYSTEM to do what it pleases with it. Does Visual Studio need some kind permission to edit a picture?

Comment: I am sorry I am not well versed with Visual Studio. Maybe you can check your settings again from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html).